# Add commands to client language

Tags: vscode-extensions

I previously made an extension with a language support for g-code. Now I'm converting it into a language server. The problem is that my extension had some commands which I registered on the client side. When using the exact same code on the language client (the client of the language server) it does not work. Does someone have an idea why that could be?

I tried copy pasting all the dependencies etc. but with no success.

Here is the source code of the package.json of the language client:

```json
{
    "name": "lsp-sample-client",
    "description": "VSCode part of a language server",
    "author": "Microsoft Corporation",
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "publisher": "vscode",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.63.0"
    },
    "main": "./out/extension.js",
    "activationEvents": [
        "onLanguage:gcode",
        "onLanguage:cpl"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber1",
                "title": "Renumber Step 1"
            },
            {
                "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber10",
                "title": "Renumber Step 10"
            },
            {
                "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber100",
                "title": "Renumber Step 100"
            },
            {
                "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber1000",
                "title": "Renumber Step 1000"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "editor/context": [
                {
                    "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber1",
                    "title": "Renumber Step 1"
                },
                {
                    "when": "editorLangId == gcode || editorLangId == cpl",
                    "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber10",
                    "title": "Renumber Step 10"
                },
                {
                    "when": "editorLangId == gcode || editorLangId == cpl",
                    "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber100",
                    "title": "Renumber Step 100"
                },
                {
                    "when": "editorLangId == gcode || editorLangId == cpl",
                    "command": "lineNumberer.Renumber1000",
                    "title": "Renumber Step 1000"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vscode-languageclient": "^7.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/vscode": "^1.63.0",
        "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.2"
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the client extension.ts:

```js
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

import * as path from 'path';
import { workspace, ExtensionContext, commands } from 'vscode';

import {
    LanguageClient,
    LanguageClientOptions,
    ServerOptions,
    TransportKind
} from 'vscode-languageclient/node';
import { incrementLineNumbersBy } from './lineNumberer/lineNumberer';

let client: LanguageClient;

export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {

    const renumber1 = commands.registerCommand('lineNumberer.Renumber1', () => {

        const step = 1;

        incrementLineNumbersBy(step);
    });

    const renumber10 = commands.registerCommand('lineNumberer.Renumber10', () => {

        const step = 10;

        incrementLineNumbersBy(step);
    });

    const renumber100 = commands.registerCommand('lineNumberer.Renumber100', () => {

        const step = 100;

        incrementLineNumbersBy(step);
    });

    const renumber1000 = commands.registerCommand('lineNumberer.Renumber1000', () => {

        const step = 1000;

        incrementLineNumbersBy(step);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(renumber1);
    context.subscriptions.push(renumber10);
    context.subscriptions.push(renumber100);
    context.subscriptions.push(renumber1000);


    // The server is implemented in node
    const serverModule = context.asAbsolutePath(
        path.join('server', 'out', 'server.js')
    );

    // If the extension is launched in debug mode then the debug server options are used
    // Otherwise the run options are used
    const serverOptions: ServerOptions = {
        run: { module: serverModule, transport: TransportKind.ipc },
        debug: {
            module: serverModule,
            transport: TransportKind.ipc,
        }
    };

    // Options to control the language client
    const clientOptions: LanguageClientOptions = {
        // Register the server for gcode and cpl documents
        documentSelector: [
            { scheme: 'file', language: 'gcode' },
            { scheme: 'file', language: 'cpl' }
        ],
        synchronize: {
            // Notify the server about file changes to '.clientrc files contained in the workspace
            fileEvents: workspace.createFileSystemWatcher('**/.clientrc')
        }
    };

    // Create the language client and start the client.
    client = new LanguageClient(
        'languageServerExample',
        'Language Server Example',
        serverOptions,
        clientOptions
    );

    // Start the client. This will also launch the server
    client.start();
}

export function deactivate(): Thenable<void> | undefined {
    if (!client) {
        return undefined;
    }
    return client.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem myself. The problem was that you have to add the contributes commands part in the ./package.json (the outer most package.json) and not the one from the language client.